# Use pattern of global ex command found on a line to substitute in another line

Tags: search, replace, global-command, filetype-fortran

In my fortran code I have a lot of blocks like the following

```
subroutine name(arg1,arg2,arg3,...)
:
end subroutine
```

and I want them to become

```
subroutine name(arg1,arg2,arg3,...)
:
end subroutine name
```

Where each of these blocks can be indented by any amount of spaces (in fact, such blocks can be nested).
I tried with the command

```
:g/^ *subroutine \(.*\)/;/end subrout/s/end subroutine/& \1
```

which changes each line (I read it in the bottom line) changing nothing, just as the buffer `\1` is empty.
The command

```
:g/^ *subroutine \(.*\)/;/end subrout/s/end subroutine/& hello
```

works well, but is obviously not what I want.
So the question is: how can I use in the replacement string a pattern matched by the global ex command `:g`?

**EDIT**
I'm editing the question since, at the time I posted it , I hurriedly accepted the answer which was an answer to the specific case I referred to, but not to the title of the question, which is a little bit more general.

I go to the point. I have a file like the following (non-sense just to make it as general as possible):

```
# sec1
fun1  are you a function?
fun2 no.
fun3 ok, nice to meet you!

# 2nd part
first line
third line
ops (it was the second)
there were 3 lines in the preceding #

# fourth group
now there's just one
and foreveeer
```

(In fact, the lines following each `#`-line are hundreds.)

I have to make substitutions in every line following each `#`-line (and preceding the following `#`-line); these substitutions should all use the text after the leading `#`-line (or part of it). An example of want I would like to achieve is

```
# sec1
fun1 in sec1  are you a function?
fun2 in sec1 no.
fun3 in sec1 ok, nice to meet you!

# 2nd part
first in 2nd line
third in 2nd line
ops in 2nd (it was the second)
there in 2nd were 3 lines in the preceding #

# fourth group
now in fourth there's just one
and in fourth foreveeer
```

Note that only the first word following `#` is inserted in the following lines.

So, as I already said, I'd like to know if the pattern of the `:g` command can be used in substitute string. I'm so interested in this answer since it is very annoying to register a macro (one wrong keystroke means starting all over again!), whereas a command like this,

```
:g/^# \(\<\w\+\>\)/+;/^#/- s/\(\<\w\+\>\)\(.\+$\)/\2 \1 \3
```

would be perfect! ... And it's hard for me to belive that there's no way to use a command that does the job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of `:global`, [matchit](https://github.com/tmhedberg/matchit) and `:normal!`:

```
:g/^\s*subroutine/norm ^whye^%$p
```

Explanation:

- `:g/^\s*subroutine`: for all lines matching `^\s*subroutine`, do:
- `normal`: enter normal mode (<del>`!` means no mappings</del> do **not** use `norm!`, as the `!` removes the call to matchit (thanks @SatoKatsura))
- `^` go to the first non-blank character (not `0`, to handle nested subroutines)
- `whye`: go to second word (name), go back 1 character (space) and copy it (the space is to make the pasting at the end a bit easier)
- `^%`: go back to the first non-blank character and use matchit to find the matching `end`
- `$p`: paste `name` (with a leading whitespace) at the end of the line

Comment: `norm!` kills `%` from `matchit`.  Solution: `:%g/^\s*subroutine/norm ^whye^%$p`.

Comment: Ah you're right. I actually did test it, but I used `norm` instead of `norm!`, as I was fairly confident I didn't have any custom setting interfering here… Good catch, and thanks for the correction.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I fail to see why you need to use `:%g`. I tried both on a buffer with distinct and nested subroutines (and with `-u NONE`) and got the same results in both cases. I though `:global`'s default range was `1,$` (ie `%`). In what case would the `%` make a difference?

Answer (score 5):

A possible workaround is to use a macro:

```
qa/^subroutine<CR>f<space>/end subroutine<CR>$pq
```

Which can be detailled like this:

```
qa                  Record a macro in the a register
/^subroutine<CR>    Go to the next occurence of a subroutine declaration
f<space>            Go to the space separating "subroutine" and the name
y$                  Yank till the end of line (i.e. the name)
/end subroutine<CR> Go to the next occurence of "end subroutine"
$p                  Put the name at the end of the line
q                   Stop recording the macro
```

You can then execute your macro with `X@a` where `X` is the number of subroutines to proceed

Comment: Well, I use a lot of macros (register c to comment, u to uncomment, t to tab and so on), so one more macro wouldn't be a problem. Anyway my point of view is that I could erroneously overwrite the macro with something non sense without even realizing it (q is near w and I'm not yet a master in touch typing). So, for now, I'm going to hope/wait for other answers.

Comment: Fortran can have nested subroutines.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the macro solution by [@statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox), modified to deal with subroutine parameters and nested subroutines.  This assumes you also have installed [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39):

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> - clear register `@a`
- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - start recording in register `@a`
- `/^\s*subroutine\zs<CR>` - search for `subroutine`; `\zs` leaves cursor on the space following it
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - yank the name; `2` because we want to include the space, `w` because we want a `word` (this stops at `(` etc.)
- <kbd>h</kbd> - go left, to the end of `subroutine`
- <kbd>%</kbd> - go to matching `end subroutine` (three cheers for `matchit`)
- <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - paste the name
- <kbd>_</kbd> - go to the first non-blank character, i.e. the beginning of  (the) `end`
- <kbd>%</kbd> - back to the matching `subroutine`
- <kbd>j</kbd> - down, to look for more `subroutine`s
- <kbd>0</kbd> - go to the beginning of line, so that not to miss a `subroutine` on the current line
- <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - call the current macro recursively
- <kbd>q</kbd> - end macro

To run it:

- `:set nowrapscan` - avoid an infinite loop: the macro will bail out when it reaches the bottom of file
- <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - go to top of file
- <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - run macro

Answer (score 3):

You can go with a substitute command:

```
:%s/\v(^subroutine (.+)\_.{-}end subroutine)/\1 \2
```

This match the whole `subroutine / end subroutine`in the group 1 and the subroutine name in the group 2, and concatenate them.

The `{-}` is a non-greedy `*` so it will stop at the first element found.

`\_.` match everything and a `new-line`.

Comment: This won't work, Fortran can have nested subroutines.

Comment: I know, but OP have not specified anything about it. His proposition and the other answer won't work with nested subroutines. Matching "closing" subroutine is another question altogether.

Comment: It isn't a big deal, `matchit` can handle nested subroutines.